# How to stop unwanted internal queries getting logged in postgresql log?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, logging, psql

I have enabled logging in postgresql(pg_log). But my log files fill up the disk easily due to a specific query. I came to know it is generated by pgadmin4 monitoring. I don't want this to be logged.

```
SELECT 'session_stats' AS chart_name, pg_catalog.row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476)) AS "Total",
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active' AND datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476))  AS "Active",
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'idle' AND datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476))  AS "Idle"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tps_stats' AS chart_name, pg_catalog.row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(xact_commit) + sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476)) AS "Transactions",
       (SELECT sum(xact_commit) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476)) AS "Commits",
       (SELECT sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476)) AS "Rollbacks"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ti_stats' AS chart_name, pg_catalog.row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(tup_inserted) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476)) AS "Inserts",
       (SELECT sum(tup_updated) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476)) AS "Updates",
       (SELECT sum(tup_deleted) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476)) AS "Deletes"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'to_stats' AS chart_name, pg_catalog.row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(tup_fetched) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476)) AS "Fetched",
       (SELECT sum(tup_returned) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476)) AS "Returned"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bio_stats' AS chart_name, pg_catalog.row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(blks_read) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476)) AS "Reads",
       (SELECT sum(blks_hit) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 461476)) AS "Hits"
    ) t
```

I just want the application queries to be listed in the logs. I don't want the internal queries to be listed. Can anyone point out what properties should I change for this in postgresql.conf.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by internal? This query is not being generate by Postgres itself. Guessing it is coming from some monitoring program. In any case you can't separate the logging out by program/application.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver As you guessed, It is generated by pgadmin4 monitoring. I dont want this to be logged. How to stop?

Comment: In `postgresql.conf` change `log_statement` from `all` to `mod`. See here [What to log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) for more details.